# Environment variables - undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I want to use `environment variables`. I made a custom `react app environment`.

Everything is ok, the app runs properly, no errors. But the variables from `.env` file gives `undefined` and the `process.env` gives an `empty object`.

I added [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and `REACT_APP` prefix to the variable.

And in `webpack.config.js` file i added `node: { fs: 'empty' }`, from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-285598881)

Here are my [configurations](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/1bea111149f2a5cc697d1d6dd7194d9c?ts=2).

Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: try https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv to use `.env` variables

Comment: Added `dotenv` same result.

Comment: `REACT_APP` prefix is a feature of create-react-app cli, not of react. try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

Comment: @grecdev A very good article in setting up `.env` file for react server-side as well as for client-side app. https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5

Comment: @grecdev Also I can see you are not using any parameter after --env in your start script this might override all the variable defined in .env file, either use --env in the script or use .env file.

Comment: Hmmm let me check it.

Comment: @DarpanRangari I will remove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

1. Uninstall `dotenv`
2. Remove these two from main `app.js` file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config();
```

3. Remove the flag `--env` from `npm start` script.
4. Remove `node: { fs: 'empty' }` from `webpack.config.js` file
5. Install [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack), and follow the instructions from there.

No need for `REACT_APP` prefix.

Fixed [configuration files](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/1bea111149f2a5cc697d1d6dd7194d9c)

Comment: I ever had an issue like this, I solved it using dotenv It worked, in development mode. But when I'm trying to build for production, it was failed.

Comment: hmm let me check it in production aswell

Comment: Works both `development` and `production`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `REACT_APP` in front of the variable name you want to have

eg:/

```
REACT_APP_YOUR_VAR="something"
```

You don't need to install Dotenv or something else, because React has its own.

Answer (score 0):

try https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv to use `.env` variables

In your entry JS file add below code snippet (maybe your `./src/assets/js/app.js`)

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()
```

and restart your app.

Comment: I added that, aswell as `node: { fs: 'empty' },` in the `webpack.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack.DefinePlugin

```
 plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        })
    ],
```

Then in your code simply use process.env.NODE_ENV to access ENV variable

Comment: Resolved, `dotenv-webpack` much easier cleaner. For my case at least.